# Making an ajax call inside a successful one can be considered bad practice?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

Let's take the following piece of code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: dataType,
    url: 'someUrl',
    success: function(result){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: dataType,
            url: 'anotherUrl',
            data: queryToSearch,
            success: function(anotherResult){
                (do something that uses the first one result)
            },
            error: MyObj.defaultAjaxError
        });
    },
    error: MyObj.defaultAjaxError
    });
```

Can this be considered a bad practice? Does it have any hit on performance? If yes, is there a better way to do something like this?

Comment: Do both calls need to happen sequentially, or can they happen simultaneously?  I don't see anything in the second AJAX call which depends on the first one.

Comment: i have been using this for a while and never had any issues ... i don't think there is other ways than `asyn:false` you can use to hold on ajax calls

Comment: Yes, @David, sorry for not being clear about that, i've edited the code :D

Comment: There would be only two negative effects using nested method, you are creating maybe unneccessary closures, and adding more to callback spagetti. I suggest you use promises for that. Your code would be more readable at least.

Comment: This is the way to do it.

Comment: @MinaGabriel: Now *that* would be bad practice :)  For the original question, however, I agree with the other comments so far that there really isn't any way around it.  If Step 2 depends on the results of Step 1, then it can't execute until Step 1 is complete.  The same is true of all logical operations, not just AJAX calls.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use Promises. Hopefully, [Promises/A](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Promises/A) (as [implemented in jQuery *1.8+* Deferred Objects](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/)), then:

```
$.ajax({..}) // Promise 1
 .fail(function () {
    // Oops! This will fire if (and only if) Promise 1 failed.
 })
 .then(function () {
    // This will only fire if the first request had no error - was "done"
    // We then return a NEW promise for the 2nd request. In a proper
    // Promises/A, 'then' returns a (new) promise. (jQuery < 1.8 is broken.)
    return $.ajax({..}) // Promise 2
 })
 // Note that these are for the 2nd promise which has been returned from
 // the 'then' above OR from a 2nd promise created automatically by the default
 // failHandler.
 .fail(function () {
    // Oops! This will fire if EITHER the promises (AJAX calls) fails.
    // This happens because we are either binding to our Promise 2
    // or to the auto-rejected promise returned from the default failHandler.
 })
 .done(function () {
    // 2nd promise done - means both are done!
 })
```

Using `when` is not appropriate, because that would be "in parallel". (Actually, `when` *could* be used with a "stub" promise that is wired to be accepted when the 2nd call completes - however this doesn't benefit from `then` chaining and it's not possible to meaningfully use the promise from the 2nd call directly for serial execution.)

One interesting thing to note is that *`fail` and `done` are just shorthands for/restricted forms of `then`*. These methods can (and should) be used for clarity of intent/code.

Comment: Seems interesting... What'd be the benefits of handling Promises instead chaining ajax calls inside success?

Comment: @AlexandreWiechersVaz Less nesting and cleaner "flow" of code. It's just another concept/idiom - not required, but useful.

Comment: Understood... So it'd be more of a readability issue... One more question. What if the second one fails, do the fail chain to the first one?

Comment: Link with some discussion regarding Deferreds: http://www.erichynds.com/blog/using-deferreds-in-jquery

Comment: @AlexandreWiechersVaz I've updated comments in my example to correct some misleading data.

Comment: Thank you @user2246674, it's clear as water now! But wouldn't it affect performance if bot fail handlers get called?

Comment: "One interesting thing to note is that fail and done are just shorthands for/restricted forms of then. They can (and should) be used for clarity of intent." - So they basically do something like .then(function(){//handle code if(code ok){ return done }else{ return fail}}); ??

Comment: @AlexandreWiechersVaz It depends on the "handler" called, which is positional. `fail(f)` -> `then(null, f)`, `fail(f).done(d)` -> `then(d, f)`

Comment: Ooooh got it! Thanks for the amazing explanation

Answer (score 3):

If you need the callbacks to run sequentially, you need to do it this way.  If they need to be done in parallel ( order is not guaranteed ), than you should not do it this way.  It is not  good or bad practice issue.  It is a matter of what you need to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing explicitly wrong with doing it this way, but you may look into using [jQuery Deferred Objects.](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/)