# Jquery Ajax: How to use the result of the first ajax call the make the second call? (.then(function()))

Tags: jquery, ajax

This [post answered the question I was about to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18623202/making-an-ajax-call-inside-a-successful-one-can-be-considered-bad-practice). The only problem is that I need to use the result of the first call as argument for the second ajax call.

In fact, I need to get contacts for a certain customer. However, the only argument I have is the request from that client. I'd like to make the first call to get the client number of the client, then use that Id to query all the contacts.

Can some one provide a small code where The result of the first query is used to make the second call?

Here part of the code he wrote.

```
$.ajax({..}) // Promise 1 
 .then(function () {
  // This will only fire if the first request had no error - was "done"
  // We then return a NEW promise for the 2nd request. In a proper
  // Promises/A, 'then' returns a (new) promise. 
  return $.ajax({..}) // Promise 2
})
```

Thank for helping.

Comment: uhm... it's in the first parameter passed to your .then callback...

Comment: @KevinB, I'm not too familliar with ajax. I'd had just made another call inside the first, but I think this is supposed to be the best way to do it. Can u provide a sample how I'd do this?

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({...}).then(function (d1) {
    // d1 is the data returned from the first ajax call.
    // You can use it as a parameter to the second ajax call below.
    return $.ajax({...}).done(function (d2) {
        // d2 is the data returned from the second ajax call.
        console.log(d1, d2);
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`.then` callback(s) contain the results from the promise that it is for. In this case, it will contain three arguments, the same three that get passed to `$.ajax` success callbacks: parsed result, text status, and jqXHR Object.

```
$.ajax({..}) // Promise 1 
 .then(function (result, status, jqXHR) {
  // This will only fire if the first request had no error - was "done"
  // We then return a NEW promise for the 2nd request. In a proper
  // Promises/A, 'then' returns a (new) promise. 
  console.log(result);
  return $.ajax({..}) // Promise 2
}).done(function (contacts, status, jqXHR) {
  //...
});
```

you can use `result` to get the customer id from the response. The last .done will be triggered with the response from the 2nd promise.

Comment: Is the result in the .then function the same as the one that was returned by the first ajax call?

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work for you?

```
function getContacts(data){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: dataType,
        url: 'someotherUrl',
        data: idofclient = data.idofclient 
        success: function(data){
             console.log(data.contact);
        }
    });
}

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: dataType,
    url: 'someUrl', 
    success: function(data){
        getContacts(data); //data should have the id of the client of course
    }
});
```

Comment: I guess that should work, but I think it's not that compact as if I had used .then, but I think it should be ok.

Comment: ah, I somehow missed the .then(function()-part in your question. :)